# SWF Video with JS Controls

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, video

I'm new to flash and just need to do a simple task but I can't manage to get it to work.
I'm trying to import a video (flv) into a SWF container and need to AS functions which should be exposed to JS (using liveconnect or anything else).
These two function should toggle sound on/off and toggle play/pause. I dont need any user interface or a full featured player, just these two functions.

Does anyone know a straight foward tutorial which covers these issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly , then I think you want to trigger Actionscript functions using javascript. Well, that this possible. You need to explore the ExternalInterface class. [Here](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/638/1/Basics-of-using-the-ExternalInterface/Page1.html) are some useful tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good point start from. But to be honest, I dont want to delve deep into Flash/AS and therefore I'm looking for a copy & paste tutorial which covers also the video controls for timeline embedded videos. I think that should be a typical beginner problem?! Sorry, didn't realized that there a bunch of other tutorials available on this site. I'm going to check that out.